# SQL / w3schools / запрос помогите

Tags: sql

Задача. Получить числовую разницу между общим кол-вом всех стран (включая повторяющиеся) в колонке “Countries”, таблицы “Customers”, и кол-вом уникальных стран.

Например, если в поле “Countries” перечислены: Austria, Austria, Argentina, Mexico, то общее кол-во значений = 4, в то время, как уникальных, лишь 3, следовательно, 4 – 3 = 1. Результат, должен быть выведен в колоноку “Result”.

```
 select count(*) as 'All Countries',
   count(distinct Country) as 'Unique countries',
   (count(*) - count(distinct Country)) as Result
   from Customers;
```

Не уверен что правильно...

Comment: Ошибка только одна - вместо `COUNT(*)` следует указать `COUNT(Countries)`. Ибо `COUNT(*)` считает количество записей в таблице - в том числе и тех, в которых страна не указана (значение поля равно NULL).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказки, верное решение ниже:

```
select count(Country) as 'All Countries',
   count(distinct Country) as 'Unique countries',
   (count(Country) - count(distinct Country)) as Result
   from Customers;
```